# Google Map flickers under alert dialog due to being compressed

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I have implemented a dialog box on my marker info box click listener and the code logic is working fine, but when I show the dialog box the map is pushed up and flickers in the back ground.  I tried it on a Pixel emulator as well as Galaxy S8 and both show the map as flickering behind the alert dialog box.

Here is the image and you can not really see it flickering but the text is distorted and flickering.  It looks like its being compressed between the keyboard and top. The word ...calculating is on the bottom of the screen with no dialog so not sure why its at the top.

Any help would be appreciated.  I did check for similar questions and what I think I am after is the keyboard simply overlaying the image not pushing it up.

```
googleMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {                
                showEditTextDialog();
            }
        });

public void showEditTextDialog()
    {

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);

        final View dialogView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.mymap_marker_alert_dialog, null);
        final EditText editText = (EditText) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.alert_dialog_editText);

        // Keyboard
        final InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) this.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);

        // Auto show keyboard
        editText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean isFocused) {

                if (isFocused)
                {
                    imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, 0);
                }
            }
        });

        builder.setView(dialogView)
                .setPositiveButton("Okay", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                        String regNum = editText.getText().toString();
                        Log.d("STACKOVERFLOW", "Registration number: " + regNum);

                        // Hide keyboard
                        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(editText.getWindowToken(), 0);
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                        // Hide keyboard
                        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(editText.getWindowToken(), 0);

                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });

        AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
        alertDialog.show();
    }
```

[image: Map distorted]

Comment: After further testing, it looks like the AdView is the problem as its trying to show the add still.  Still investigating and will try and pause the ad.

Answer (score 0):

SO it was the Adview that was trying to show in the compress screen area above the keyboard.  I had to find a way to remove the adview while the keyboard was visible and then return it again on the keyboard was dismissed.  In my case I had to ensure to re-enable the adview in the Alert Dialog onclick methods and the full solution is as follows:

1. Set up your LinearLayout and note the @id for both the LinearLayout and adView.

   ```
       <TextView
           android:id="@+id/mydistanceToMarker"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
           android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
           android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
           android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
           android:gravity="fill"
           android:text="Tap to change map type."
           android:textAlignment="center"
           android:textSize="36sp"
           android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
           android:textStyle="bold" />

       <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
           xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
           android:id="@+id/myAdMapView"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_gravity="center"
           ads:adUnitId="@string/UNIT_ID"
           ads:adSize="BANNER"/>
   </LinearLayout>
   ```
2. Connect the variable to the LinearLayout

   ```
   private LinearLayout parentLinearLayout;
   ```

   and

   ```
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_my_map);
       parentLinearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.mydistanceLayout);
   ```

NOTE: I have a few LinearLayout layers in my xml file so this @id is for the LinearLayout that just contains the adView that I need to remove and re-add when needed, NOT the top level LinearLayout.

3. In my progarm logic that is not included and irrelevant, I call the Alert Dialog method

   ```
   public void showEditTextDialog()
   {
       parentLinearLayout.removeView((View) adMapView);
   ```

   Here I remove the add at the start of the Alert Dialog and since I force the keyboard to show immediately and I need the ad not to be visible.
4. Now at the OK and Cancel responses in the Alert Dialog I add the view back.

   ```
   builder.setView(dialogView).setPositiveButton("Okay", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                   @Override
                   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                     imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(editText.getWindowToken(), 0);
                       parentLinearLayout.addView((View) adMapView);
                   }
               })
               .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                   @Override
                   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {                       imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(editText.getWindowToken(), 0);
                       dialog.cancel();
                       parentLinearLayout.addView((View) adMapView);
                   }
               });
       AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
       alertDialog.show();
   ```

And this fixed the issue.  Not sure if it was the best solution and happy to edit or fix the solution if there is a better way, but it solved my issue.  Hope it helps someone in the same situation.